# работа с приложениями на сервере

Tags: php, клиент-сервер

подскажите пожалуйста, имеется некое приложение в виде .exe, мне требуется открыть это приложение на сервере, закинуть туда поступаемые данные, а после получить и в итоге выдать ответ в php, как это можно реализовать? хостинг beget, операционная система ubuntu, все манипуляции с приложением должны происходить именно на сервере, а после выдавать ответ на страницу, был бы рад, если подсказали, на каком языке можно провести эту операцию

Comment: запустить в консоли чтото через php:
exec, passthru команды
они же возвращают вывод консоли при желании. распарсивайте вывод и пишите куда вам нужно
при условии чтото запускаемое через консоль синхронное и работает быстро